# iOS App compiles but XCode 8.1 beta gives error message saying "Module 'HockeySDK' not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, hockeyapp, xcode8

My iOS App compiles but XCode gives error message saying "Module 'HockeySDK' not found".

I added **HockeySDK** both using cocoapods.

Unfortunately when I build and run the app runs but XCode gives me the error mentioned above. It looks like this:

[image]

This is my Pods folder structure:

[image]

What's going wrong?

For reference I am using XCode 8.1 beta.

Edit: I have updated to XCode 8.2.1 release version but still gives the same error.

Edit 2: The embedded framework sections shows the Pods libraries (from my understanding this should suffice):

[image]

Comment: Did you used the command "pod install" to install that library in your project?

Comment: I used pod update

Comment: I just tried with pod install but unfortunately made no difference..

Comment: In general, for issues with CocoaPods, please _always_ post your entire `Podfile`, otherwise it is very hard to help in such cases.

Comment: The issue occurs without the use of cocoapods also . Did anyone find any solution yet ?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a temporary hiccup because of a problem with a certain version of CocoaPods and some version of Xcode.
I would suggest to try to:

1. Update CocoaPods to the latest version.
2. Completely remove the integrated Pods by running `pod deintegrate` and/or manually deleting the entire `Pods` folder.
3. Run `pod install` again to do a fresh integration of all your Pods.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error usually occurs because the framework has not been manually added to the "Embedded Frameworks" section in the General Project settings.

Comment: I have followed the procedure suggested by the Hockey App for Mac. Is it possible that they missed this step?

Comment: It could be possible you never know until you try.

Comment: I tried on a separate project and still didn't work. It seems that doing in this way it would spoil the point of having cocoapods.